# Reinstall and restart modem manager (revert changes arduino script did)

Tags: bash, usb-modem, arduino, modem-manager

I'm one of those unlucky guys who ran a script as su without reading the content of the script.

I tried to install Arduino. So downloaded and uncompressed the setup. I found scripts called `install.sh` and `arduino-linux-setup.sh` ran `install.sh` then ran `arduino-linux-setup.sh`. `install.sh`is simply put the necessary files in necessary directories and create .desktop files. It's an innocent script.

But `arduino-linux-setup.sh` removed my modem-manager without even prompting for permission. The output is as follows (image).

Output of arduino-linux-setup.sh script:

[image: Output of arduino-linux-setup.sh script]

It removed modem manager by running `sudo apt-get -y remove modemmanager` Output showed the following line too.

`Created symlink /run/systemd/system/ModemManager.service -> /dev/null`

I'm including the contents of `arduino-linux-setup.sh` below.

```
refreshudev () {

    echo ""
    echo "Restarting udev"
    echo ""
    
    sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
    sudo udevadm trigger
    
    if [ -d /lib/systemd/ ]
    then
        sudo systemctl restart systemd-udevd
    else
        sudo service udev restart
    fi

}

groupsfunc () {
    echo "Add User to dialout,tty, uucp, plugdev groups"

    sudo groupadd plugdev
    sudo groupadd dialout
    sudo usermod -a -G tty $1
    sudo usermod -a -G dialout $1
    sudo usermod -a -G uucp $1
    sudo usermod -a -G plugdev $1

}

acmrules () {
    echo "# Setting serial port rules"

    cat <<EOF
    KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", TAG+="udev-acl", TAG+="uaccess", OWNER="$1"
    KERNEL=="ttyACM[0-9]*", TAG+="udev-acl", TAG+="uaccess", OWNER="$1"
    EOF
}

openocdrules () {
    echo "# Adding Arduino M0/M0 Pro, Primo UDEV Rules for CMSIS-DAP port"

    cat <<EOF
    ACTION!="add|change", GOTO="openocd_rules_end"
    SUBSYSTEM!="usb|tty|hidraw", GOTO="openocd_rules_end"

    #Please keep this list sorted by VID:PID

    #CMSIS-DAP compatible adapters
    ATTRS{product}=="*CMSIS-DAP*", MODE="664", GROUP="plugdev"

    LABEL="openocd_rules_end"
    EOF
}

avrisprules () {
    echo "# Adding AVRisp UDEV rules"
    
    cat <<EOF
    SUBSYSTEM!="usb_device", ACTION!="add", GOTO="avrisp_end"
    # Atmel Corp. JTAG ICE mkII
    ATTR{idVendor}=="03eb", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2103", MODE="660", GROUP="dialout"
    # Atmel Corp. AVRISP mkII
    ATTR{idVendor}=="03eb", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2104", MODE="660", GROUP="dialout"
    # Atmel Corp. Dragon
    ATTR{idVendor}=="03eb", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2107", MODE="660", GROUP="dialout"
    
    LABEL="avrisp_end"
    EOF
    
}

dfustm32rules () {
        echo "# Adding STM32 bootloader mode UDEV rules"
    
    cat <<EOF
    # Example udev rules (usually placed in /etc/udev/rules.d)
    # Makes STM32 DfuSe device writeable for the "plugdev" group
    
    ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0483", ATTRS{idProduct}=="df11", MODE="664", GROUP="plugdev", TAG+="uaccess"
    EOF
    
}

dfuarduino101rules (){
# Arduino 101 in DFU Mode"

    cat <<EOF
    SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ENV{ID_REVISION}=="8087", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="0ab6", MODE="0666", ENV{ID_MM_DEVICE_IGNORE}="1", ENV{ID_MM_CANDIDATE}="0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="8087", ATTR{idProduct}=="0aba", MODE="0666", ENV{ID_MM_DEVICE_IGNORE}="1"
    EOF
}

removemm () {
    # Removing modem manager
    sudo apt-get -y remove modemmanager
}


if [ "$1" = "" ]
then
    echo ""
    echo "Run the script with command ./arduino-linux-setup.sh \$USER"
    echo ""
else

    [ `whoami` != $1 ] && echo "" && echo "The user name is not the right one, please double-check it !" && echo "" && exit 1

    groupsfunc $1

    removemm
    acmrules $1 > /tmp/90-extraacl.rules
    openocdrules > /tmp/98-openocd.rules
    avrisprules > /tmp/avrisp.rules
    dfustm32rules > /tmp/40-dfuse.rules
    dfuarduino101rules > /tmp/99-arduino-101.rules

    sudo mv /tmp/*.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/

    refreshudev

    echo "*********** Please Reboot your system ************"
fi
```

### My question

After running the script I wasn't able to use my use Dongle.

How do I revert the things arduino script did to my system and make my usb dongle work again. I reinstalled modem-manager but it still not working. Is there something to do with that symlink created. Currently I'm unable to connect to internet from my laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this will do it.

```
rm /etc/udev/rules.d/90-extraacl.rules
rm /etc/udev/rules.d/98-openocd.rules
rm /etc/udev/rules.d/avrisp.rules
rm /etc/udev/rules.d/40-dfuse.rules
rm /etc/udev/rules.d/99-arduino-101.rules
rm /run/systemd/system/ModemManager.service
```

Then try this.

```
systemctl enable ModemManager.service
```

To see if it recreates the proper link to it, it should I see nothing that shows it deleted the service file only clobbering it with new link to `/dev/null` in the directory that symbolic link is supposed to start from. Then reboot and hopefully it is back to normal. Edit all commands run with sudo at the front of them if you do not know this.

Comment: It worked! I already removed the .rules files but was unable to figure out how to start modem manager service. Thanks to you, I enabled it. Thanks a lot for bring me my internet connection back.

Comment: You are welcome, it is nice I could help you with it. Any service is like that, that has the `systemd` scripting in the `.service` files. They can be `enabled`, `start`, `reload`, `stop` and `disable` are the ones I have used. I am certain there are many more options to it. Edit now I think of it you can refer to them by name too without the .service on the end. Oh and now it pops in my head, for the most import one I use, the `status` to find out how  your services is going if is having problems it will tell you so or if it  goes good it shows working.

Comment: I would add it was not a malicious script it just had a bad result for you. Everything that it was doing was legitimate for installing some kind of a communication device, the `tty*` devices it was creating in the rules files.

Comment: Edited the question to reflect this real script without knowing what it did, being run, a little to late to edit my comment on it not being that way though, to include this ...

Comment: I thought removing a system utility secretly(without even prompting the user) is a feature of malware. I think I'm right because that's what malware does.

Comment: Malware does it behind your back without any notice mainly. You had every opportunity to read that script to try to understand what it did before hand. Should a `we are going to remove this program do you want to continue` been stated by the script, it most certainly would be there if I had written it. Or would have been explained in the `README` that is usually contained in downloads like this, or from packages  installed from a repository.

Comment: There was no README or warnings. Almost all the legit software include `we are going to remove this program do you want to continue` line. Yeah, you are right, it's not a binary, it's just a script. But I can't agree with assuming that the user is agreed to remove their system utility just because it's a human readable script.